# What is this `job_desc_msg_t` format that I need to submit jobs to SLURM via the Perl API?

Tags: perl, slurm

The [Perl API for SLURM](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man3/Slurm.3pm.html) indicates that to submit a job with the API requires that we give it a "job description" (`$job_desc` or `$job_desc_msg`), which has the structure `job_desc_msg_t` but it doesn't tell what `job_desc_msg_t` is.

update: I found it in [slurm.h starting at line 1162](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/b8190e5d60dfca3da9a40f72c4edc060b9d27d79/slurm/slurm.h.in#L1162), so I'm guessing that I will need to pass in a hash with a similar structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly what you must do according to the man page.

> Typicaly, C structures are converted to (maybe blessed) Perl hash
>          references, with field names as hash keys. Arrays in C are converted to
>          arrays in Perl. For example, there is a structure "job_info_msg_t":
>
> ```
> typedef struct job_info_msg {
>     time_t last_update;     /* time of latest info */
>     uint32_t record_count;  /* number of records */
>     job_info_t *job_array;  /* the job records */
> } job_info_msg_t;
> ```
>
> This will be converted to a hash reference with the following
>          structure:
>
> ```
> {
>     last_update => 1285847672,
>     job_array => [ {account => 'test', alloc_node => 'ln0', alloc_sid => 1234, ...},
>                    {account => 'debug', alloc_node => 'ln2', alloc_sid => 5678, ...},
>                    ...
>                  ]
> }
> ```
>
> Note the missing of the "record_count" field in the hash. It can be
>          derived from the number of elements in array "job_array".
>
> To pass parameters to the API functions, use the corresponding hash
>          references, for example:
>
> ```
> $rc = $slurm->update_node({node_names => 'node[0-7]', node_state => NODE_STATE_DRAIN});
> ```
>
> Please see "<slurm/slurm.h>" for the definition of the structures.