# How can I configure SLURM at the user level (e.g. with something like a ".slurmrc")?

Tags: slurm

Is there something like `.slurmrc` for SLURM that would allow each user to set their own defaults for parameters that they would normally specify on the command line.

For example, I run 95% of my jobs on what I'll call our `HighMem` partition. Since my routine jobs can easily go over the default of 1GB, I almost always request 10GB of RAM. To make the best use of my time, I would like to put the partition and RAM requests in a configuration file so that I don't have to type them in all the time. So, instead of typing the following:

```
sbatch --partition=HighMem --mem=10G script.sh
```

I could just type this:

```
sbatch script.sh
```

I tried searching for multiple variations on "SLURM user-level configuration" and it seemed that all SLURM-related hits dealt with [`slurm.conf` (a global-level configuration file)](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html).

I even tried creating `slurm.conf` and `.slurmrc` in my home directory, just in case that worked, but they didn't have any effect on the partition used.

---

update 1
Yes, I thought about [`scontrol`](https://slurm.schedmd.com/scontrol.html), but the only configuration file it deals with is global and most parameters in it aren't even relevant for a normal user.

---

update 2

My supervisor pointed out the SLURM Perl API to me. The [last time I looked at it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079725), it seemed too complicated to me, but this time upon looking at the code for [`https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/contribs/perlapi/libslurm/perl/t/06-complete.t`](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/contribs/perlapi/libslurm/perl/t/06-complete.t), it would seem that it wouldn't too be hard to create a script that behaves similar to `sbatch` that reads in a default configuration file and sets the desired parameters. However, I haven't had any success in setting the 'std_out' to a file name that gets written to.

Comment: It remains unclear what you want the user to be able to control? For many things it is obvious that only administrators can change, as SLURM deals with resources that are shared by all users.

Comment: @TomdeGeus Thank you for asking for clarification. I hope my updated question is more clear.

Comment: Much more clear! Can't help you out on the solution though. Personally, I just use [a script](https://github.com/tdegeus/GooseSLURM/blob/master/bin/Gscript) to generate something that has my defaults and some slight case specific adaptions. It's quite case specific, and for sure not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your example is representative, defining an alias

```
alias sbatch='sbatch --partition=HighMem --mem=10G'
```

could be the easiest way. Alternatively, a Bash function could also be used

```
sbatch() {
command sbatch --partition=HighMem --mem=10G "$@" 
}
```

Put any of these in your `.bash_profile` for persistence.

Comment: Perfect! This works because when more than one of the same option is passed to Slurm, it will replace the previous option. I tried it with `sbatch --partition=ThisPartitionDoesNotExist --parttion=Bar --wrap='ls > ls.txt'` and it ran on the partition `Bar` without complaining about the dummy one.

Comment: Alternatively, there are a bunch of 'input environment variables' that you can set that work like their '--option' counterpart: `SBATCH_TIMELIMIT` for `--time` and `SLURM_MEM_PER_NODE` for `--mem` in your case.